# adding to mysql and deleting on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

there is my script

```
require('dbcon2.php');


  if(isset($_GET['submit1'])) { 
        if(isset($_POST['post_autor']) && isset($_POST['post_tresc'])) {

            mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO news (tresc, autor) VALUES ('$_POST[post_tresc]', '$_POST[post_autor]')");

        }

  } elseif(isset($_GET['submit2'])) {

        if(isset($_POST['post_id_news2'])) {
            $usun = $_POST['post_id_news2'];

            mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM news WHERE id_news = ".$usun."");
        }   else {
            echo 'Proba usunieca postu o pustym id.';
        }

    }
```

I wanted to do this on one page, before adding deleting (hehe) it was ok, but I wanted to do delete option and nothing works, zero errors I just press inputs and nothing happends.

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style type="text/css">
            .cztery {
                    background: pink;
                    height:705px; 
                    width:40%;
                    float:right;
                }
            .czteryipol {
                    background: red;
                    height:705px; 
                    width:40%;
                    float:right;
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="cztery">
            <h1 align="center">
                <a href="html/news_podg.php" target="_blink">
                    PODGLĄD
                </a>
            </h1>
            <table border="5"  bordercolor="#a64dff" align="center" style="max-width:20px;">
                <?php
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT autor,id_news FROM news GROUP BY id_news");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id_news'].'</td><td>'.$row['autor'].'</td></tr>';
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="czteryipol">
            <h1 align="center">
                EDYCJA
            </h1>
             <form action="kwadrat.php?go=czesc" method="post" id="usrform" align="center">

                <h2>
                    Autor<br> <input type="text" size="20" name="post_autor"/>
                </h2>


                <h2>
                    Dodaj artykuł: 
                </h2>
                <textarea name="post_tresc" align="center" form="usrform"></textarea><br>

            <input name="submit1" type="submit" value="OK"/><br>
        </form>

         <form action="kwadrat.php?go=czesc" method="post" id="usrform" align="center">
            <h1 align="center">
                Usuń artykuł
            </h1>   
            <h2>
                    Numer artykułu<br> <input type="text" size="5" name="post_id_news2"/>
            </h2>   
            <input name="submit2" value="OK" type="submit"/><br>  
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If someone can tell me where is my mistake I will be very grateful

**FINAL EDIT:**

Thanks for help, I fixed that:

instead of this

```
($_GET['submit1'])
```

do

```
($_POST['submit1'])
```

Comment: I think its all about submits

Comment: Please post the HTML as well if the current two answers don't point you in the right direction...

Comment: Parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably .....
Instead of `if(isset($_GET['submit1']))`
Use `if(isset($_POST['submit1']))`

Answer (score 0):

`if(isset($_POST['post_id_news2'])) { //<- Here is your culprit I think
        $usun = $_POST['post_id_news'];`

You are checking for `post_id_news2` (note 2 at the end) parameter and then trying to use `post_id_news` parameter.

I don't know which one you actually use, but in your case they should be the same.

Also I suggest you read this:
[Escaping parameters for MySQL queries](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some debugging stuff: 1. Check to make sure the second submit is actually called `#debug1`. 2. Next check for MySQL errors `#debug2` for the `delete` statement.

```
require('dbcon2.php');


if(isset($_GET['submit1'])) { 

    echo 'submit1: was called'; #debug1

    if(isset($_POST['post_autor']) && isset($_POST['post_tresc'])) {

        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO news (tresc, autor) VALUES ('$_POST[post_tresc]', '$_POST[post_autor]')");

    }
} 
elseif(isset($_GET['submit2'])) {

    echo 'submit2: was called'; #debug1

    if(isset($_POST['post_id_news2'])) {
        $usun = $_POST['post_id_news'];

        #debug2
        if(!mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM news WHERE id_news = ".$usun."")) {
                echo 'MySQL error: ' . mysqli_error($connect);
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Proba usunieca postu o pustym id.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, not a missing curly brace... What do you mean error?

Comment: I meant i just got "error on line 99" which is the last one, but i have already fixed that, thanks for help anyways